# RandomForestClassifer throwing estimator error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am attempting to build a stacking classifier using multiple combinations of available models, however, when I have a RandomForestClassifier the loop throws an error. Here is what I have attempted:

> 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'estimators_'. Did you mean: 'estimator_'?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier, StackingClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = load_breast_cancer()
X, y = data.data, data.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, random_state=1250, criterion='entropy', max_depth=2, min_impurity_decrease=0.5)
RF1 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, random_state=1250, criterion='entropy', max_depth=2, min_impurity_decrease=0.2, oob_score=True)
ABC = AdaBoostClassifier(random_state=1250)
GBC = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=1250)

stackModels = [RF, RF1, GBC, ABC]

from itertools import combinations

classifier_combinations = [ list(np.array(stackModels)[list(x)]) for x in list(combinations(range(len(stackModels)), 2))]

Stackresults = {'estimators': [],'final_estimaor': [], 'accuracy': []}
for list_class in classifier_combinations:
    for classify in stackModels:
        CLASS = StackingClassifier(estimators = list_class, final_estimator=classify)
        CLASS.fit(X_train, y_train)
        ypred = CLASS.predict(X_test)
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, ypred)
        Stackresults['accuracy'].append(accuracy)
        Stackresults['estimators'].append(list_class)
        Stackresults['final_estimator'].append(classify)
```

FULL TRACEBACK:

```
/var/folders/dr/9wh_z8y10fl79chj86pq7knc0000gn/T/ipykernel_7755/3533362225.py in <module>
     24     for classify in stackModels:
     25         CLASS = StackingClassifier(estimators = list_class, final_estimator=classify)
---> 26         CLASS.fit(X_train, y_train)
     27         ypred = CLASS.predict(X_test)
     28         accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, ypred)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    486         self._le = LabelEncoder().fit(y)
    487         self.classes_ = self._le.classes_
--> 488         return super().fit(X, self._le.transform(y), sample_weight)
    489 
    490     @if_delegate_has_method(delegate="final_estimator_")

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_stacking.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    148         # all_estimators contains all estimators, the one to be fitted and the
    149         # 'drop' string.
--> 150         names, all_estimators = self._validate_estimators()
    151         self._validate_final_estimator()
    152 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_base.py in _validate_estimators(self)
    245                 " of (string, estimator) tuples."
...
--> 188         return iter(self.estimators_)
    189 
    190 

AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'estimators_'
```

Comment: Please, always provide the whole traceback

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Added the full traceback

Comment: I found the error, essentially, stackingClassifier has to take a list of tuples, whereby, a name of the model has to be included. something like: `[('RF',RF), ('ABC',ABC)]`, but mine produces something like `[RF, ABC]`